# Google draw in HTML page?

Tags: html, drawable, draw

I need to make a webpage where a building can be drawn (in 2D view) using polygons. The best solution would be to embed Google Draw into an HTML page.

How could I do that?

Other solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: [A search for "Google Draw"](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+draw) does not yield any explanatory results. Would you mind explaining what this is, and why you think it is the best solution?

Comment: Do u mean to embed Google Draw API?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/CNx8H/

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it can draw rectangles only with DIVs.